# Wordpress filter custom posts by multi terms of of a taxonomy

Tags: plugin-development

I have this headache for couple of days now.

I am on a project where it requires to sort/filter custom posts by both single and multiple terms of a taxonomy. There should be additional filter for ordering the posts by ASC/DESC.

Basically like this filter on the page: https://app.romwod.com/workouts

I have tried to use dozens of plugins and gone through several online code samples, but failed to find appropriate one, the closer one was: Beautiful taxonomy filters but it does not provide multiple terms filtering option and there is no way to present the filter as a list of items rather than a dropdown.

My development page: http://mizanit.com/programming/

Stackexchange is my last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [WP Advanced Search](http://wpadvancedsearch.com/) ?

I think that will make the solution for you.